# Why does retrieving Class codes with QuickBooks IPP.NET SDK fail with a ValidationError?

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform

Using the following code:

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Class sampleClass = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Class();
var classes = ParentClient.DataService.FindAll<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Class>(sampleClass, 1, 1000);
```

This works fine against QuickBooks Online, but fails when using the same API sync'd to a QuickBooks Desktop instance, and fails with a generic `ValidationError`. Why?

Edit: This is the POST:

`select * from Class startPosition 1 maxResults 1000`

And this is the response:

`{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"Operation failed, see details for error","code":"1000"}],"type":"Validation"},"time":"2014-02-25T03:51:08.300Z"}`

Answer (score 0):

Please enable logging for request and response file and check the details of the error in the response file.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0

Comment: The logs didn't contain any errors; added some more info in this question with the request/response.

Comment: Please try just this - select * from Class and see if you get a response

Answer (score 0):

Paging limit is 500 for QBD.

Following query will work.

```
select * from Class startPosition 1 maxResults 500
```

Thanks